# Simple conditionals parse when they shouldn't

Tags: ee2, conditionals, parse-order

I have a page that's set up like this:

```
{if segment_2 == ""}
  // show categories
{/if}
{if segment_2 != ""}
  // show entries
{/if}
```

I'm using simple conditionals ( as opposed to if:else ) because I don't want
the contents of the second part to be parsed when they shouldn't.

But, when my segment_2 is empty, EE still goes inside that tag and parses everything, resulting in a slow page load.

There's nothing out of the ordinary inside that simple conditional ( EE tags, an embed and a little bit of php ( parsed on output ) )

But **something forces EE to ignore the parsing error and parse everything inside the conditional**. Question is: what ?

I know I could probably just use switchee and be done with it, but I shouldn't have to. I want to figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: First narrow it down by removing the innards chunk-by-chunk

Comment: could it be because there's an advanced conditional inside my simple conditional ?

Comment: yes, probably... does it work if you remove that?

Comment: yep, that fixes it. Could you write down an detailed answer soI can upvote it ? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like putting an if:else inside your simple conditional makes it an advanced conditional, thus affecting parsing order.

In other words, suppose segment_1 is empty:

```
{if segment_1 != ""}
   EE tags placed here won't be parsed
{/if}
```

vs.

```
{if segment_1 != ""}

   EE tags placed here WILL be parsed

   {if segment_1 != ""}
      // something here
   {if:else}
      // something here
    {/if}
{/if}
```

( luckily, we have switchee: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee )

Comment: Yes. Any advanced conditional inside a simple conditional will make everything advanced. You need to use something like SwitchEE or If:Else to fix this behavior.

Answer (score 10):

I'd recommend you taking a look at Mark Croxton's if:else and switchee plugins. They allow you to use advanced conditionals (and switches) without the overhead of having all your conditions parsed, which is the default EE behaviour.

They're a fantastic way of optimising your site and I'd encourage you to start using them whenever you have a need for anything other than a simple conditional.

Here are the links to Mark's addons:

- **Switchee:** http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee
- **IfElse:** http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse

Take care

Jim

Comment: Like I said: "I know I could probably just use switchee and be done with it, but I shouldn't have to. I want to figure out what goes wrong."

Answer (score 2):

Conditionals are always parsed, they are only displayed if the condition is passed. If you want to avoid this behaviour you need to use IfElse by Croxton or switchee also by Croxton.

Comment: But when segment_2 != "" returns false, it should parse the content of that conditional, right ?

Comment: That's not right - the innards of SIMPLE conditionals like janvl's example will not be parsed unless they themselves contain advanced conditionals (or possibly other things to be uncovered by the question)

Comment: "unless they themselves contain advanced conditionals" I think that's the problem. Wasn't aware of that..

Comment: could be I've mis-remembered the rules here.

Comment: To put it more accurately, I think it's the case that nested conditionals will get processed first, so if the parser finds a nested advanced conditional it will get parsed before the wrapping simple conditional. That's why switchee requires parse="inward".